# How do I create an AJAX call to an http.handlfun

Tags: ajax, go

I have a Golang web application. On one of the pages I wish to call a new page from AJAX.

The call fails - nothing happens. I think the http.ResponseWrite is invalid.

I have called the same endpoint from a navbar menu and get the result I expect but when call from Ajax it fails.

I am using the default server.mux

The funchandler looks like this:

```
func inviteSuppliers(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write([]byte("Hello Cruel World!"))
}


func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()

    // --- BELOW IS THE HANDLER REF
    mux.HandleFunc("/invitesupplier", inviteSuppliers)

    // --- EN
  
    mux.Handle("/assets/",
        http.StripPrefix("/assets",
        http.FileServer(http.Dir("./assets"))))

    mux.HandleFunc("/robots.txt", robots)
    //mux.HandleFunc("/whitepapers", whitePapers)
    mux.HandleFunc("/sitemap", siteMap)
    mux.HandleFunc("/sitemap.xml", siteMap)

    mux.HandleFunc("/privacy", pageRederer)
    mux.HandleFunc("/cookiepolicy", pageRederer)

    // -- Profile
    mux.HandleFunc("/bankdetails", pageRederer)
    mux.HandleFunc("/api/bankdetails", SaveBankdetails)
    mux.HandleFunc("/api/getbankdetails", GetBankdetails)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(WebPort, mux))
}
```

Called from a bootstrap navbar it works as expected. Call from AJAX:

```js
 $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "/invitesupplier",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",         
     });
```

I can put a breakpoint on the funhandler and both methods hit the endpoint the difference is that the call from ajax does not work. Hence I think there is something wrong with the w http.ResponseWriter.

Is there a way in which I can test this?

Comment: If the handler works when called from the navbar, but not when called from ajax, then its not the handler's fault but ajax's, especially given how simplistic the handler is. You should check the Browser network console to see what the ajax problem is. For example, if the ajax code is served from a domain that's different from the domain which is serving the Go backend, then CORS would be a very likely cause of the problem.

Comment: What does "the call from ajax does not work" mean? The code as shown doesn't do anything with the response, so how would you know that it "doesn't work"? Note that the response is not a valid JSON document, but the client seems to expect JSON. Is that the issue?

Comment: what does it mean when the ajax does not work?

Comment: If it works from curl but not from a javascript fetch (side note why jQuery, just use vanilla js) then it could be a CORS issue. It would be useful to know what the response was and or the console output from the browser. Further side note, when writing questions remove anything not relevant to the question, e.g. the other handler registrations